# Using RESTful web service with JSF2

Tags: jsf, service

I am working on an enterprise application which has several modules.

I want to go with `REST` web service and `JSF` but i don't know What is best way to consume `REST` web service with `JSF`?

What is the best way to authenticate request for `REST API` web service?

Do we need to authenticate every client request before processing it?